# ubuntu/linux vpn connection with certificate

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, certificate, linux-networking

I want to connect to a windows pptp vpn server which accepts only connections with a CA certficate.

From windows im able to do it easily (since its windows of course and native supported) but from my ubuntu 10.04 im not able to setup the vpn to authenticate using a certificate.

any help/hint?

Comment: i guess there is no way to do it...

Comment: What kind of vpn? As in what version of windows and what are the settings...

Answer (score 1):

Sure there's a way to do it, you'll need to muck about in some source code to do it though.

You need to use PPTP with certificates. Certificates aren't supported out of the box in linux. [But there is a patch available](http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/ppp/index.html).

Look through the [documentation](http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/ppp/doc.html), give it a try, and report back.

Comment: i will check it out and let you know, any other a bit easier hint would be also appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think there's anything easier. And it's really not that hard to do. Read the documentation, it should take (at most) 20 minutes or so.

Comment: It took more then 20 minutes to do it, but I succeeded somehow.

Comment: \o/, 20 minutes was to give you a false confidence to go ahead and try. :-)